# What is the difference between _id and thread_id?

Tags: android

I find there are two fields _id and thread_id in SMS database, What is the difference between _id and thread_id ? 
If I want to delete a sms by ID, which field should I use?  _id or thread_id ? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `_id` is the primary autoincrement key for the sms `ContentProvider`, the `thread_id` is the id of a particular conversation

Comment: Thanks! but  if I want to delete a sms by ID, which field should I use? _id or thread_id ?

Comment: you want to delete a single sms or the entire conversation?

Comment: and if want to delete particular conservation like user want to delete a single number chat like send and receive both messages so what should i use ?